# Unity android app's launcher icon suddenly changes to android default logo, and the name to package name

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

the title speaks itself about the issue. After reinstalling the game I can see my icon, but after a while it gets changed to android default logo, and the name under it - to the package name (on samsung galaxy note 4).

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

*p.s. internal storage 26.40 GB used out of 32 GB, 
     portable storage 2.27  GB used out of 14.80 GB,
(if that tells something)*

Comment: My quess is manifest :)

Comment: Can you add What version of Unity and Android SDK?

Comment: 25.1.7 (the latest revision) for Android SDK and 5.2.4 Unity version.